# How to configure kannel without a gsm modem

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

Is it possible to really send SMS, on behalf of my customer's phone number, without using a GSM modem from kannel?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a regular phone connected to a PC acting as a GSM Modem, the only limitation that comes to my mind is that the phones usually support much less SMS per second.

My recommendation is NOT to use a GSM modem unless you really need to. Instead use a SMSC provider such as:

www.clickatell.com
www.hqsms.com
...etc

They have a significant number of API that you can integrate with your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect number of cell phones via data cable to computer and send SMS or even make a call. For example good ol' Siemens C35 is perfectly suited for that.

Answer (score -1):

There are some online services that let you use a custom sender, even a string instead of number. Unfortunately availability may vary among countries.

I know Mensatek in Spain.